Unable to register Apple ID
I tried registering Apple ID and after verifying my email and phone number I can neither log in with the credentials that I had set, nor request a new password using "Forgot Password" option. I get generic errors, like "This Apple ID is either not valid or not supported". I cannot contact Apple support, because my country is not on the list of supported countries. I tried registering with another email and the same phone number, but this also failed.
Do you have any idea what might have happened here and how could I proceed? Some things that might be an issue are:

I used an old MacbookPro, 2015 model, but it is still supported
I'm using protonmail.com email
I'm from Serbia


Are you in Serbia?

@IconDaemon Yes and I haven't used a VPN, so my IP is from Serbia.

What version of macOS is running on this MBP?

@IconDaemon The latest Monterey, 12.7.5. I also tried through Safari.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253333121?sortBy=best may help you contact Apple. Includes https://support.apple.com/en-euro for unlisted European countries.

@Gilby Thanks, but all those links lead me back to the page where I need to select a country from a list where Serbia is not present.
